# Ninject Convention-based binding with different lifestyle

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-extensions

I am trying to use Ninject 3 Convention-based bindings, and  would like to specify which lifestyle a service should be bound with at bind-time.

I am trying to use the code below, without success; my app errors saying that my services haven't been bound.  I know I can write my own binder and do all of the reflection work myself, but this looked rather nice.  Am I missing something?

```
Kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesMatching("PatentSpoiler*")
      .SelectAllClasses()
      .BindDefaultInterface()
      .Configure(cfg =>
       {
          cfg.InTransientScope();
          cfg.WhenClassHas<BindAsASingletonAttribute>().InSingletonScope();
          cfg.WhenClassHas<BindInRequestScopeAttribute>().InRequestScope();
       }));
```

Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Configure` callback you are putting together a configuration which is used on all bindings and when you write multiple `WhenClassHas` and `In...Scope` statements you are basically overriding your own settings so all your type bindings will use the last statement `cfg.WhenClassHas<BindInRequestScopeAttribute>().InRequestScope();`.

To solve this you need to use the second overload of `Configure` where you get the currently bound type and based on its attributes register your type with the correct scope:

```
using Ninject.Infrastructure.Language; //needed for HasAttribute<T>

//...

Kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesMatching("PatentSpoiler*")
      .SelectAllClasses()
      .BindDefaultInterface()
      .Configure((cfg, type) =>
      {
          if (type.HasAttribute<BindAsASingletonAttribute>())
              cfg.InSingletonScope();
          else if (type.HasAttribute<BindInRequestScopeAttribute>())
              cfg.InRequestScope();
          else
              cfg.InTransientScope();
      }));
```

Comment: Ah! I was hoping each statement would just mutate the configuration if the predicates matched.  I saw the other delegate but thiught I read it was the service, rather than the implementation (quite a productive session haha!). Ill check it when I get home and mark it then, thanks